# Kendo UI grid-not able to add/create records

Tags: javascript, php, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i am new on kendo UI framework.I am using grid.  The problem is the table gets updated successfully but when i add/create new record ,nothing happens.New record doesn't get added to the database.
Here is my index.php file

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "data/employees.php",
                    update: {
                           url: "data/employees.php",
                           type: "POST"
                       },
                    create: {
                           url: "data/create.php",
                          type: "PUT"
                             }
              },
                pageSize: 20,
                error: function(e) {
                  alert(e.responseText);
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "data",
                    model: {
                         id: "id",
                         fields: {
                         first_name: { editable: false },
                         last_name: { validation: { required: true} }
                                 }
                           }
                }
            },
            columns: [{ field: "first_name" }, { field: "last_name" }],
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            editable: true,
            pageable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            groupable: true,
            filterable: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is create.php file

```
    <?php
    $link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Unable To Connect To Database Server");
    mysql_select_db("northwind") or die("Unable To Connect To Northwind");   
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    //Determine the request type
    $verb=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    //handle a get
    if($verb=="PUT"){
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_PUT["last_name"]);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_PUT["first_name"]);

    $rs = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Employees (first_name, last_name) VALUES (" .$firstname ."," .$lastname .")");

    if ($rs) {
    echo json_encode($rs);
  }
  else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo "Update failed for EmployeeID: " .$lastname;
  }
 }

 ?>
```

And this is employees.php

```
 <?php
    $link = mysql_pconnect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Unable To Connect To Database Server");
    mysql_select_db("northwind") or die("Unable To Connect To Northwind");   
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    //Determine the request type
    $verb=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
    //handle a get
    if($verb=="GET"){
      $arr=array();
      $rs=mysql_query("SELECT id, last_name, first_name FROM Employees");
      while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }
   echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($arr). "}";
 }
 //handle a post
 if($verb=="POST"){
    $lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["last_name"]);
    $employeeId = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);

    $rs = mysql_query("UPDATE Employees SET last_name = '" .$lastName ."' WHERE id = " .$employeeId);

    if ($rs) {
    echo json_encode($rs);
  }
  else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo "Update failed for EmployeeID: " .$employeeId;
  }
 }

 ?>
```

I am not able to solve this:(
Please help.

Comment: Are you getting an error returned? What is the structure of your Employees table? For example, is the id column set up as Autoincrement?

Comment: What do you see in dev tools when when you submit?

Comment: no error in dev tools@whipdancer